# Can I make a sentence with "impressive of"?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, phrase-usage

Is the word "impressive of" an appropriate preposition? Do you think the sentence is correct:

> The museum is **impressive of** its design.

Can I make a sentence this way or correct me please.

Comment: No, but perhaps: **The design of the museum is impressive.** This reorders the same words, except *its* is changed to *the*.

Comment: "The museum is impressive *in* its design."

Answer (score 1):

No.  "impressive" doesn't take a complement with "of". This question is currently the second [Google result for "impressive of"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22impressive+of%22).  The other top Google results with "impressive of" are using the construction "most [adjective] of [collective noun]" such as "the most impressive of all the desert monasteries".